# ubuntu:terminal+ssh+vim, resize

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vim

Background:

OS:ubuntu 12.04

Display: two, one is laptop, and another is a extended monitor, which is bigger.

Problem:

Open a gnome-terminal in the bigger display, and log on the remote Linux server using ssh.

Then open vim and code. But after I drag the terminal to the laptop monitor, the problem I

have is that the width/size of the remote terminal doesn't fill my Terminal app. window,

only part.

How can I make it fill the entire Terminal area?

Comment: It should resize automatically. Did you try `<C-l>`?

Comment: Yes, pressing <C-l> is useless.

Comment: What's the output of `$ echo $TERM` locally and on the server?

Comment: local is xterm.

Comment: and the server is  xterm too.

Comment: Hmm, testing with a roughly similar setup (`TERM=xterm` in gnome terminal and in a remote host) I don't have any resizing issue. Try `$ echo $COLUMNS` and `$ echo $LINES` in the big window and the smaller one to see if your terminal actually notices that it's resized.

Answer (score 2):

After resizing your terminal, you need use `resize` command.

`` eval `resize` ``

nowadays just `resize` works.

`resize`

This command changes `LINES`, `COLUMNS` environment variable.

You can check your current terminal size with `echo $LINES $COLUNNS`.
try `echo $LINES $COLUMNS` before and after `resize`.